# sshd AllowUsers + AllowGroups

Tags: 20.04, sshd

Background:
We have about 500 linux (Ununtu 20.04) resources deployed for the users. We are using sssd for authentication and ID provider is AD. We allow each user to ssh to only their system by configuring AllowUsers  in sshd_config. Admins before me have also configuerd root and ansible user for remote access. They have setup ssh keys for root and ansible users.

Problem:
I dont like how they currently ssh to the system as root for any form of support. I have setup a group in AD: admingroup and added the administrator's usernames to that group so that they can log in to the systems using their own account. I have defined AllowGroups admingroup in sshd_conf as well.

The issue I am having is that the end user defined in AllowUsers is not part of the admingroup defined in AllowGroup. This ends up preventing all ssh access.

From what I understand, if I am defining AllowUsers and AllowGroups then the said username needs to be part of the admingroups. Else no one can ssh to the system. Is my understanding correct?

If yes then how would I go about adding ssh access to all of my linux resources for the admins while still letting only single user for which the resource is assigned to ssh to it.

Any help/direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as soon as I asked the question, I ran in to some threads that addresses this exact scenario.

In sshd_config, comment out AllowUsers and AllowGroups lines and at the very end of the config (and this is important that it is at the very end) add the following and restart sshd service

```
Match Group <group name>
    AllowUsers <end user>
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turning it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.